# Unable to run Console Application in c#

Tags: c#

My friend gave me an .exe file for Console Application. By some trial software, I got the code for the file.
The name of the folder is ConsoleApplication2.  I made files and pasted it in under it.

Now when I try to debug , I get the errors like

```
..System.Data.DataRow
'System.Data.DataRow.ItemArray.get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor
'System.Data.DataRow.this[int].get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor    
'System.Data.DataRowCollection.this[int].get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor
```

for many many lines.

```
 table2.Rows.Add(row.get_ItemArray());
 if (table2.Rows.get_Count() != 0)
```

This are two example of lines. I think this lines are proper. I have just made some mistake like copied code under wrong category. Forgot to change anything ???

please can u help me out.

Comment: Console applications and `asp.net` are not compatible (and in fact, are exactly opposite each other). The first is designed to run on a local computer, the other is designed to run in a web browser. Which one are you actually asking about?

Comment: I want to run on a local computer..console application

Comment: Then why did you include the `asp.net` tag?

Comment: ok. could you suggest me anything on this ?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta has already done so with his answer (and JeremyThompson added more info as well). If you're not going to read the answers, we can't help you here.

Comment: @user2163048 you need to read up on programming, Here's a bunch of freely available books: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books, good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You are attempting to read the value of a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) using its "hidden" accessor method. That's not allowed. You should instead reference the property value like this:

```
table2.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
if (table2.Rows.Count != 0)
```

Comment: row.get_ItemArray()); and Rows.get_Item..what should i do ?

Comment: What do you mean, @user2163048? Use my code as an example. Also: use MSDN as a reference. Here's the docs for [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) and [DataRowCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.aspx). It'll show you what methods and properties are available to use.

Comment: If I have a line like row2.get_Item(strTargetAttribute).ToString() == strArray[0]
what should i do ??

Comment: @user2163048, where are you getting the `get_` prefixes from? a decompiler? Follow Michael and Fernando's comments. All you have to do is remove these `get_` and `set_` prefixes. FYI: When you add a Row to a DataTable usually you do it like `DataTable dt = new DataTable();dt.Columns.Add("Col");DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();dr[0] = "value";dt.Rows.Add(dr);`

Comment: This source is pretty messy, even for a decompiler, @user2163048. If you're new to programming, you're in for some pain here. Can you get the original source code?

Comment: Yes I am new to programing and i cant get the original code. So you think, this code and the original code differs??
Almost all errors are solved but for line like row2.get_Item(strTargetAttribute).ToString() == strArray[0], I cant remove the error

Comment: Yes, this code and the original code differ significantly. You saw the property errors already. The variable names are lost, and that's going to be annoying for you. This last problem? Try `row2.Item[strTargetAttribute].ToString() == strArray[0]` (note the braces in place of parentheses).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta there is no thing like item,, so i cant use, row2.item only option i am seeing is row2.itemarray.
I used Reflector as a decompiler

Comment: Yes there is, @user2163048. A DataRow has an [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx) property. Are you sure you got the capitalization correct? Also: try [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). You might get better results.

Comment: No I am not getting, hope I am not missing any directive. I have used 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Answer (score 3):

Is that your code or did you got it from some decompiler?

get_ItemArray is a method generated by the compiler....

try removing get_ and set_

---

You can "Save code" using ILSpy (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpdevelop/files/ILSpy/2.0/ILSpy_Master_2.1.0.1603_RTW_Binaries.zip/download)

Select the assembly and click on "File->Save Code" that will export it to a project.

But, why you can't get the source code? Is it your code? is it a product you are trying not to pay for customization?

Comment: I dont have the original code. I had the exe, i got it from a decompiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
I dont have the original code. I had the exe, i got it from a decompiler.
```

Download [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) from RedGate and install [Denis Bauer's File Dissasembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) plugin.

Load the EXE into Reflector > Click the File Dissasemlber button to decompile the EXE back to a Solution with Project(s) and source files.

Comment: how'd you get the source code out? did you manually copy it into a Project to compile/debug?

Comment: Try out Denis Bauer's File Dissasembler plugin its so much easier than reconstructing the source into Projects/Solution manually.